# "The situation made everyone worried about the future" VS "The situation made everyone worry about the future"

Tags: sentence-choice

Confusion between

> The situation made everyone worried about the future.

and

> The situation made everyone worry about the future.

To me, it seems both are grammatical. Clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both are correct.

In the first sentence they use the past participle (worried) after the verb *to make* (made). We use this construction not only with participles but also with adjectives (although the past participle performs the function of the adjective in this case):

> He made me happy. The news made me sad. Her voice made me worried.

All the sentences above are about someone starting **feeling** **somehow**: happy, sad or worried.

In the second sentence they use the construction "make + verb." This time "make" means *to force someone (to do something)*:

> The film made me cry. The story made me laugh. The situation made me worry.

The sentences above are about someone starting **doing** **something**.